# Multiple Images in one slick carousel dot using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slick.js

I'm working on a slick carousel and I want each dots to have multiple images in it. Like 4 images on the first dot before it moves to the next dot then 3 images on the second dot before it moves to the final dot.

I was able to do it with the next button but having trouble with the previous button. Well, I'm not that sure about the next button but at least it works as I want it to.

#### index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="slick/slick.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="slick/slick-theme.css" />
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Ellie</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>

<body style="background-color: white;">
    <div class="wrap transparent-bg">
        <div>
            <ol class="ProgressBar">
                <li class="ProgressBar-step is-current">
                    <svg class="ProgressBar-icon">
                        <use xlink:href="#checkmark-bold" />
                    </svg> <span class="ProgressBar-stepLabel">Build It</span> </li>
                <li class="ProgressBar-step">
                    <svg class="ProgressBar-icon">
                        <use xlink:href="#checkmark-bold" />
                    </svg> <span class="ProgressBar-stepLabel">Connect It</span> </li>
                <li class="ProgressBar-step">
                    <svg class="ProgressBar-icon">
                        <use xlink:href="#checkmark-bold" />
                    </svg> <span class="ProgressBar-stepLabel">Activate</span> </li>

            </ol>
        </div>
        <div class="box">
            <div class="slider">
                <div class="single-item">
                    <div>
                        <div class="text">
                            <h1>Starters (1.0)</h1>
                            <p>Build the power cable (Needed: <span class="power-adapter">Power Adapter, Micro-USB cable</span> and Plug n' Play hub)</p>
                        </div>
                        <img src="img/0.png">

                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <div class="text">
                            <h1>Starters (1.1)</h1>
                            <p>Build the power cable (Needed: <span class="power-adapter">Power Adapter, Micro-USB cable</span>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                        <img src="img/1.png">

                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <div class="text">
                            <h1>Starters (1.2)</h1>
                            <p>Build the power cable (Needed: <span class="power-adapter">Power Adapter, Micro-USB cable</span>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                        <img src="img/2.png">

                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <div class="text">
                            <h1>Starters (1.3)</h1>
                            <p>Build the power cable (Needed: <span class="power-adapter">Power Adapter, Micro-USB cable</span>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                        <img src="img/3.png">

                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <div class="text">
                            <h1>Plug it in (2.0)</h1>
                            <p>Plug the power adapter in to the outlet closest to your router.</p>
                        </div>
                        <img src="img/4.png">

                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <div class="text">
                            <h1>Wait for the light (2.1)</h1>
                            <p>You should see two green lights after a few seconds</p>
                        </div>
                        <img src="img/5.png">

                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <div class="text">
                            <h1>Connect to the hub (2.2)</h1>
                            <p>Change your Wi-Fi on this device</p>
                        </div>
                        <img src="img/6.png">
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <div class="text">
                            <h1>Activate (3.0)</h1>
                            <p>Let's go to the activation page <a href="#">Click Here</a>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                        <img src="img/7.png">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="nav-buttons">
                <div class="nav-size" id="prev-pos">
                    <a class="prev" id="pref-fl" href=""><img src="img/left.png"><span class="nav-text"></span>Previous</a>
                </div>
                <div class="nav-size" id="next-pos"><a class="next" id="next-fl" href=""><span class="nav-text">Next</span><img src="img/right.png"></a> </div>
            </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="slick/slick.min.js"></script>
    <script type="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

#### script.js

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

        /*DEFINE PROGRESS BAR*/
        var $bar = $(".ProgressBar");

        /*SLICK OPTIONS*/
        $('.single-item').slick({
            arrows: true,
            prevArrow: $('.prev'),
            nextArrow: $('.next'),
            dots: false,
            infinite: false,
            waitForAnimate: false,
            speed: 500,
            swipe: true
        });

        $(".next").on("click", function() {

            /*Get the number of the current slide*/
            var currentSlide = $('.single-item').slick('slickCurrentSlide');

            /*Check if this is an intermediary step*/
            if (currentSlide == 2) {
                /*do nothing, this is an intermediary step*/
            } else {
                moveSlide('next');
            }

        });
        $(".prev").on("click", function() {

            /*Get the number of the current slide*/
            var currentSlide = $('.single-item').slick('slickCurrentSlide');

            /*Check if this is an intermediary step*/
            if (currentSlide == 1) {
                /*do nothing, this is an intermediary step*/
            } else {
                moveSlide('prev');
            }

        });

        /*HANDLE SWIPING*/
        $('.single-item').on('swipe', function(e, b) {
            /*IF SWIPING LEFT OR NEXT*/
            if (b.currentDirection == 0) {
                moveSlide('next');
            }
            /*IF SWIPING RIGHT OR PREV*/
            else if (b.currentDirection == 1) {
                moveSlide('prev');
            }
        })

        /*FUNCTION TO HANDLE ALL SLIDE MOVEMENT*/
        /*ACCEPTS ONE ARGUMENT 'dir' for direction*/
        function moveSlide(dir) {
            /*GET CURRENT SLIDE*/
            var currentSlide = $('.single-item').slick('slickCurrentSlide');
            if (dir == 'next') {
                if ($bar.children().last().hasClass("is-current") || (currentSlide >= 1 && currentSlide < 4) || (currentSlide >= 5 && currentSlide < 7)) {
                    //Do nothing
                } else {
                    if ($bar.children(".is-current").length > 0) {
                        $bar.children(".is-current").removeClass("is-current").addClass("is-complete").next().addClass("is-current");
                    } else {
                        $bar.children().first().addClass("is-current");
                    }
                }
            } else if (dir == 'prev') {
                if ($bar.children().first().hasClass("is-current") || (currentSlide >= 1 && currentSlide < 4) || (currentSlide >= 5 && currentSlide < 7)) {
                    //Do nothing
                } else {
                    if ($bar.children(".is-current").length > 0) {
                        $bar.children(".is-current").removeClass("is-current").prev().removeClass("is-complete").addClass("is-current");
                    } else {
                        $bar.children(".is-complete").last().removeClass("is-complete").addClass("is-current");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

#### style.css

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: 'HelveticaNeueLTPro-Lt';
}

.transparent-bg {
    position: static;
}

.wrap {
    max-width: 1060px;
    width: 96%;
    margin: auto; 
}

.clear:before {
    content: ' ';
    display: table;
}

.clear:after {
    content: ' ';
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}
.clear {
    clear: both;
}

.slider {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.box {
    padding: 0px 20px 50px;
}

.single-item {
    padding: 20px 0 50px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black; 
}

.single-item img {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.prev, .next {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    color: #4C5C62; 
}

.nav-buttons img {
    width: 20px;
    height: 15px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
}

.slick-dots {
  top: 0;  
}

.text {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    color: #4C5C62;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
}

.text h1 {
    font-size: 28px;
}

.text p {
    font-size: 16px;
}

.nav-text {
    padding: 0 10px;
}

.power-adapter {
    font-weight: 700;
}

.nav-size {
    /*width: 480px;*/
}
#prev-pos {   
    float: left;
    /*border-right: 1px solid black;*/
}

#next-pos {
    float: right;
}

#prev-fl {
    float: left;
}
#next-fl {
    float: right;
}

.slick-dotted.slick-slider {
    margin-bottom: 10px !important;
}

.ProgressBar {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 2em 0 3em;
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.ProgressBar-step {
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    &:before,
    &:after {
    content: "";
    height: 0.5em;
    background-color: $gray;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 100%;
    left: -50%;
    top: calc(50% - .5em);
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    transition: all .25s ease-out;
}

&:first-child:before,
&:first-child:after { 
    display: none; 
}

&:after {
    background-color: $blue;
    width: 0%;
}

&.is-complete + &.is-current:after,
&.is-complete + &.is-complete:after {
    width: 100%;
    }
}

.ProgressBar {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 2em 0 3em;
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-pack: justify;
    -ms-flex-pack: justify;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.ProgressBar-step {
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}
.ProgressBar-step:before, .ProgressBar-step:after {
    content: "";
    height: 0.5em;
    background-color: #9F9FA3;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 100%;
    left: -50%;
    top: calc(50% - .25em);
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    -webkit-transition: all .25s ease-out;
    transition: all .25s ease-out;
}
.ProgressBar-step:first-child:before, .ProgressBar-step:first-child:after {
    display: none;
}
.ProgressBar-step:after {
    background-color: #00637C;
    width: 0%;
}
.ProgressBar-step.is-complete + .ProgressBar-step.is-current:after, .ProgressBar-step.is-complete + .ProgressBar-step.is-complete:after {
    width: 100%;
}

.ProgressBar-icon {
    width: 1.5em;
    height: 1.5em;
    background-color: #9F9FA3;
    fill: #9F9FA3;
    border-radius: 50%;
    padding: 0.5em;
    max-width: 100%;
    z-index: 10;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-transition: all .25s ease-out;
    transition: all .25s ease-out;
}
.is-current .ProgressBar-icon {
    fill: #00637C;
    background-color: #00637C;
}
.is-complete .ProgressBar-icon {
    fill: #DBF1FF;
    background-color: #00637C;
}

.ProgressBar-stepLabel {
    display: block;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #9F9FA3;
    position: absolute;
    padding-top: 0.5em;
    width: 100%;
    -webkit-transition: all .25s ease-out;
    transition: all .25s ease-out;
}
.is-current > .ProgressBar-stepLabel, .is-complete > .ProgressBar-stepLabel {
    color: #00637C;
}

.wrapper {
    max-width: 1000px;
    margin: 4em auto;
    font-size: 16px;
}

/*FOR DESKTOP STYLES*/
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    .text {
        padding-left: 50px;
    }

}
```

Comment: You should try posting the rest of the code as well so people can try it themselves and test the code in the nice runnable snippets that SO has.

Comment: Okay. I edited the post and inserted the html. Where can I insert the css? Should I just include it after the html?

Comment: Put your html, js, and css in 3 different codeblocks. Don't include style tags or script stags in the css or js blocks.

Comment: right now when I click on previous next i will send post request to server